# Codeigniter 4 validation upload file with rule extension is not work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have an import feature and this my code

```
public function import($id = NULL)
    {
        if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'post') {
            if (empty($id) && $id != '0') {
                $rules = [
                    'template' => [
                        'label' => 'Template',
                        'rules' => 'uploaded[template]|ext_in[template,xlsx]'
                    ]
                ];

                if (!$this->validate($rules)) {
                    return $this->respond([
                        'type' => 'failed',
                        'message' => $this->validator->getError("template")
                    ]);
                }

                if ($file = $this->request->getFile('template')) {
                    if ($file->isValid() && !$file->hasMoved()) {
                        $newName = $file->getRandomName();
                        $file->move(WRITEPATH . "cache", $newName);

                        try {
                            $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
                            $spreadsheet = $reader->load(WRITEPATH . "cache" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $newName);
                            $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

                            if (count($sheetData) < 2) {
                                throw new \Exception("Unable to import empty files");
                            }

                            return $this->respond([
                                'type' => 'success',
                                'token' => $newName,
                                'rows' => count($sheetData) - 1
                            ]);
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                            return $this->respond([
                                'type' => 'failed',
                                'message' => $e->getMessage()
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $token = $this->request->getPost('token');
                $last = $this->request->getPost('last');
                $filePath = WRITEPATH . "cache" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $token;

                if (!$this->model->importExcel($filePath, $id)) {
                    return $this->respond([
                        'type' => 'failed',
                        'message' => 'Failed to import kpi',
                    ]);
                }

                if ($last == '1' && file_exists($filePath)) {
                    unlink($filePath);
                }

                return $this->respond([
                    'type' => 'success',
                    'message' => 'The kpi were imported successfully',
                ]);
            }
        }

        $data = [
            'formAction' => base_url("scorecard-tbcci/reporting/master-kpi/import"),
            'formMethod' => 'POST',
        ];

        echo view('ScorecardTbcci\Views\Reporting\Kpis\ImportFormView', $data);
    }
```

the problem is, when I upload *xlsx* file. this file doesn't passed the validation. error warning will appear **"Upload doesn't have a valid file extention"**. so I try with *xls* file and I change the rule too but it same. When I change rule with *csv* and upload csv file. it passed the validation. i don't know what's the problem. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a dd($_FILES) when you upload a xlsx file and check the respective mime type.

Then compare that to your app/config/mimes.php and check if that mime type is present in the xlsx array. Maybe the file you're uploading has a mime type that is not present in the config file.